# How to express vector with another vectors known?

Tags: geometry, vector-spaces, vectors, triangles, vector-analysis

$3$ points $ABC$ on a plane, $O$ as origins. 
$OA = \vec a$, $OB= \vec b$, $OC = \vec c$. Point $M$ inside $\triangle ABC$. And $\triangle MAB : \triangle MBC : \triangle MCA = 2 : 3 : 5$.

A straight line $BM$ intersect side $AC$ at $N$. 
Express $OM$ in terms of vector $a,b,c$.

Can you give me some hint? I have been thinking, what i got is, 
$BM : MN = 1 : 1.$
$AB : BC = 2 : 3$
$\vec AB = OB - OA = \vec b - \vec a$
$\vec CB = OB - OC = \vec b - \vec c$

$\vec OM = OB + BM$

$\vec BM = \frac 12 BN$
Then, i have difficulity in expressing $BN$ in terms of vector $a,b,c$.

Comment: "Express $OM$ in terms of vectors $a,b,c$." But this has nothing to do with $N$...

Comment: Are you sure? Because the answer sheet says it is but not clear why

Comment: The answer sheet says what?

Comment: $BN = \frac 15 (3BA + 2BC)$ but not explain why

Comment: By the way, does the notation $AB$ refer to the line segment from $A$ to $B$, or the vector from $A$ to $B$, or the length of these?

Comment: We are talking about AB is side AB. But also vector from A to B

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that from the given $\triangle MAB : \triangle MBC : \triangle MCA = 2 : 3 : 5$, the following relationship can be derived,

$$\vec{AN} = \frac25 \vec{AC} =\frac25 (\vec{BC} - \vec{BA})$$

Then,

$$\vec{BN}  = \vec{AN} -\vec{AB} = \frac25 (\vec{BC} - \vec{BA}) +\vec{BA}
= \frac25 \vec{BC} +\frac35 \vec{BA} $$

where $\vec{BC} =\vec{c} - \vec{b} $ and $\vec{BA} =\vec{a} - \vec{b} $. Thus,

$$\vec{OM}=\vec{BM}+\vec{OB}=\frac12\vec{BN}+\vec{b}
= \frac3{10}\vec{a} + \frac12\vec{b} + \frac15\vec{c}$$

Comment: I think there is some error in the end?

Comment: @Lifeforbetter - $\vec{BA}+\vec{AC}=\vec{BC}$.

Comment: @Lifeforbetter - Note $\vec{AB} = - \vec{BA}$. also corrected a typo

Comment: Have I misunderstood the meaning of a ratio of triangles? From $$\Delta MAB:\Delta MCA=2:5$$ we should have $MA:MC=2:5$, but from $$\Delta MBC:\Delta MCA=3:5$$ we should have $MA:MC=5:3$, a contradiction.

Comment: @mr_e_man - maybe you have; those are area ratios